# Inserting varchar data into varbinary

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (ex):

**OPERATION_TYPE**

```
  ROWID(int, not null)
  ID(PK, varchar(15), not null)
  DESCRIPTION(varchar(40),null) ...
```

**OPER_TYPE_BINARY**

```
  ROWID(int,not null)
  OPERATION_TYPE_ID(PK, FK, varchar(15), not null)
  TYPE(PK, char(1), not null)
  BITS(image, null)
  BITS_LENGTH(int, not null)
```

How can I insert into `OPER_TYPE_BINARY` from `OPERATION_TYPE`?

- `OPERATION_TYPE_ID = ID`
- `TYPE = 'D'`
  ? `BITS = DESCRIPTION`
  ? `BITS_LENGTH =`

Comment: You can cast varchar to varbinary, e.g. cast(DESCRIPTION as varbinary(40)). You can then use datalength() on the result to work out its byte length, which should be the same as it's char length in this case.

Comment: Thank You! I knew the answer had to be quite simple, but all the examples I found up to now seemed to get quite confusing. muhmud, your answer worked perfectly.